# Android Browser display incorrect with both border-radius and border

Tags: android, html, css, sass

I'm having a project which need a box, having a gap between content and shadow. Here is my Sass code.

```
.avatar
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: rem-calc(160);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    img
    {
            //
    }
}
```

and the HTML code is simple:

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img href='' alt=''>
</div>
```

Please see the attached image below, I can display it correctly on modern browsers except android 4.2.2 browser. It seems that border and border radius have conflict.

[image: Android display Issue]

Comment: That is because of image height and width differs. I would suggest giving .avatar div specific width and height (for example -- width:50px; height:50px;) and then for apply css property for img tag i.e. width/height both 100%

Comment: OR you can ignore img tag by giving .avatar div specific width and height (for example -- width:50px; height:50px;) and then use property background:url(imagepath/imagename.extension); background-size:100%;

Comment: @divy3993 Thanks for your reply. Still not working for both using fix w/h and using js to fix aspect ratio.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SASS, so what does `rem-calc` do? It sounds like it may be font-size dependent...

Comment: @MrLister Ah that's just a fix width, you can see it as 160px for now.